# Android Development: Improve EditText Scrolling?

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext

Is there any way I can increase my EditText's scrolling?
I want to make it scroll like it does on the web browse, smooth and fast.
Is this possible?

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: I really need this answered, I have a 250 rep bounty going for an acceptable working answer.

Comment: Can you explain the situation a bit more ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Webview uses Smooth scrolling. A scroll view also have this property.

- Add the text view inside a Scrollview.
- Make an ID for the scrollview and create reference in your code.
- Place the EditText Within this scroll view(Make the editText to Wrap Content).

Enable Smooth Scrolling using the below method,

```
public void setSmoothScrollingEnabled(boolean smoothScrollingEnabled)
```

Control the smooth scrolling by specifying bounds for the scroll, using the below method...

```
public final void smoothScrollBy (int dx, int dy)
//dx,dy.. offset (Relative Position)

public final void smoothScrollTo (int x, int y)
//scroll to x and y (actual position)
```

You can also imitate the overscroll behavior using the following Method,

```
public void setOverScrollMode (int mode)
```

Also you can add Fling Action using the following method,..

```
public void fling (int velocityY)
```

Answer (score 1):

A better description of the current and desired behaviour would be good, however you might get the desired behaviour by embedding in a ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `CustomEditText extends EditText` class and override the `onTouch` and `onTouchEvent` methods and use these to detect gestures and then move the contents up or down.