# Fast scroll in an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, fastscroll

My EditText can have sometimes very large text (>1000 lines) and I want to be able to quickly reach the start or the end so I thought fast scroll was the solution, however it is not available for EditText, nor ScrollView, only for ListView. I found some editing apps that do have the fast scroll bar in their EditText. How did they do it? Setting `smoothScrollEnabled` on parent ScrollView doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

By quoting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5594713/5188159),

You can use a `ScrollView` and place your `EditText` inside it and mention the position of it that you need  fast/smooth scrolling.

```
    scrollview = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view) ;
    scrollview.setSmoothScrollingEnabled ( true );
    scrollview.smoothScrollBy (int dx, int dy); //dx,dy.. offset (Relative Position)
    scrollview.smoothScrollTo (int x, int y); //scroll to x and y (actual position)
```

Comment: Do I have to make the scrollbar myself? If so, how?

Comment: scrollbar or ScrollView? yes you need to add your edit text inside ScrollView

Comment: I mean will that add a scrollbar like the one added in ListView when using fast scroll? Or are you only suggesting a way to scroll manually?

Comment: @Nicolas Maltais try and see you can use fast scroll with that and those possition with starts that can be given by relatively or you can give the actual position ,if you dont need a scroll bar  i guess you can remove that as well

Comment: No that doesn't change anything, I want a draggable scrollbar to appear, like with listView's fastScroll

Comment: Please update your question. You should mention the scrollbar in your question to get relevent answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@null"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@null"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etBook"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/futurabook"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Tap to start writing ...."
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryVariant"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

</ScrollView>
```